# np.array mean to single column data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 2 column array that I calculate the mean of (thus creating column A). I would like to be able to refer to and manipulate column A, but cannot seem to save it as a new single column. Here is my specific example, 'filtered' is what I'd like to be able to save/use/ Errors are regularly `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv('/Users/myfile.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=['Time','Distance'])

x = df['Time']
y = df['Distance']

n = 25  #small n = less smoothed

fwd = pd.Series.ewm(df,span=n, adjust=True).mean()
bwd = pd.Series.ewm(df[::-1],span=n, adjust=True).mean()
filtered = np.stack(( fwd, bwd[::-1] ))
filtered2 = np.mean(filtered, axis=0)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('smoothed and raw data')
plt.plot(x,y, color = 'orange')
plt.plot(x,filtered, color='green')
plt.plot(x,fwd, color='red')
plt.plot(x[::-1],bwd, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('distance')

df['filtered2'] = pd.DataFrame(filtered, dtype='str', index=None)
print(filtered2)

smoothed_velocity = ((df.filtered2 - df.filtered2.shift(1)) /  df['Time'] - df['Time'].shift(1))

print(smoothed_velocity)
plt.subplot (2,1,2)
plt.title ('smoothed velocity')
plt.plot (smoothed_velocity, color = 'orange')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Because I define 'filtered' twice I tried changing one to a different variable with no luck. Error presented was `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (458,) and (2, 458, 2)`

Any help would be rad!

Comment: Which line do you get this error on?

Comment: There is a lot of code that is not directly related to the error you are receiving which makes it difficult to understand the issue that you are running into. The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) docs explain better than I am able to what I am referring to, hope this helps!